# Opening another WinRT app from another running app in FULL mode

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have 2 apps. I am running one in full mode and want to click a button from the first app to launch the second app . 
My problem is that my second app is getting launched but both apps are in Snapped mode. 
I programatically want to allow the other app to open in fill mode and first app should be  in the memory.

Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Store apps don't have any way to directly launch other apps. I assume you're launching a URI or file and your app is registered as the default handler (users can choose something else).

In your call to [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh701484.aspx) you can set the [DesiredRemainingView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.launcheroptions.desiredremainingview.aspx) in your [LauncherOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.launcheroptions.aspx) to indicate how much of the screen you'd like your app to keep. This is non-binding, but likely to be followed for UseNone. If there's room for UseHald (the default) then UseLess to snap/fill will likely be respected as well.